# Why does Qt Designer add so much space?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-designer

Why does Qt make so much space? How can I fix this? I just want to create two labels, two text boxes and a login button. I'm trying to make a login form.

[image]

Something like this:
[image]

Why does it need so much space to just have small buttons?

[image]

This is the nicest I've been able to get it to look, but even this looks terrible.

Comment: Please describe how you are creating that form.

Comment: I am using Qt designer, you can view the hiearchy in the obejct inspector. It lists the classes that I am using.

Comment: You need to be more specific. For example, if I open the designer and create a new Widget, then drag two push buttons onto it, box-select them, right click, and "Layout vertically", they are packed neatly together. If I then drag another push button onto the form to the right of them, then box select that 2-button layout and new button, and "Layout horizontally", they are packed neatly together. Is that how you are doing things?

Comment: No. I'm not doing that. I'm just dragging them onto the screen. With the way you are doing it, will it maintain spacing/sizing when you resize the window?

Comment: I don't think the way you are explaining would maintain spacing/sizing when you resize the window.

Comment: It will maintain values you set in the property editor according to the QSizePolicy.

Comment: What's the best way to create a login screen that's responsive?

Comment: Better first watch tutorials in youtube like that https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R6zWLfHIYJw then If you are still in confusion then ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a `Vertical Spacer` to the top and the bottom, then you will have your expected result.

> If you would like to add it through the code and not in Designer, you would need to add it on the QLayout with `QBoxLayout::addStretch(int stretch = 0)` or `QBoxLayout::addSpacing(int size)`, depending on your need

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like that? [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cW8XH.png)
You can use spacers from Qt Designer to achieve what you want, I guess.

Below is the UI code of my example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
    <class>MainWindow</class>
    <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
        <property name="geometry">
            <rect>
                <x>0</x>
                <y>0</y>
                <width>683</width>
                <height>408</height>
            </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="windowTitle">
            <string>MainWindow</string>
        </property>
        <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
            <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
                <item row="1" column="2">
                    <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_2">
                        <property name="orientation">
                            <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
                        </property>
                        <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
                            <size>
                                <width>40</width>
                                <height>20</height>
                            </size>
                        </property>
                    </spacer>
                </item>
                <item row="1" column="1">
                    <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox">
                        <property name="title">
                            <string>GroupBox</string>
                        </property>
                        <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_2">
                            <item row="1" column="0">
                                <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
                                    <property name="text">
                                        <string>TextLabel</string>
                                    </property>
                                </widget>
                            </item>
                            <item row="0" column="0">
                                <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
                                    <property name="text">
                                        <string>TextLabel</string>
                                    </property>
                                </widget>
                            </item>
                            <item row="2" column="0">
                                <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_3">
                                    <property name="orientation">
                                        <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
                                    </property>
                                    <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
                                        <size>
                                            <width>40</width>
                                            <height>20</height>
                                        </size>
                                    </property>
                                </spacer>
                            </item>
                            <item row="2" column="1">
                                <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
                                    <property name="text">
                                        <string>PushButton</string>
                                    </property>
                                </widget>
                            </item>
                            <item row="0" column="1">
                                <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit" />
                            </item>
                            <item row="1" column="1">
                                <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_2" />
                            </item>
                            <item row="2" column="2">
                                <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_4">
                                    <property name="orientation">
                                        <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
                                    </property>
                                    <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
                                        <size>
                                            <width>40</width>
                                            <height>20</height>
                                        </size>
                                    </property>
                                </spacer>
                            </item>
                        </layout>
                    </widget>
                </item>
                <item row="1" column="0">
                    <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
                        <property name="orientation">
                            <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
                        </property>
                        <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
                            <size>
                                <width>40</width>
                                <height>20</height>
                            </size>
                        </property>
                    </spacer>
                </item>
                <item row="0" column="1">
                    <spacer name="verticalSpacer">
                        <property name="orientation">
                            <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
                        </property>
                        <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
                            <size>
                                <width>20</width>
                                <height>40</height>
                            </size>
                        </property>
                    </spacer>
                </item>
                <item row="2" column="1">
                    <spacer name="verticalSpacer_2">
                        <property name="orientation">
                            <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
                        </property>
                        <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
                            <size>
                                <width>20</width>
                                <height>40</height>
                            </size>
                        </property>
                    </spacer>
                </item>
            </layout>
        </widget>
        <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
            <property name="geometry">
                <rect>
                    <x>0</x>
                    <y>0</y>
                    <width>683</width>
                    <height>21</height>
                </rect>
            </property>
        </widget>
        <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar" />
    </widget>
    <resources />
    <connections />
</ui>
```

Moreover, a quick tip for you, if you are a beginner, I consider this as a mistake to use two layouts when you do not need two of them: in your example, remove the "formLayout" and format your "LoginScreen" as a QFormLayout instead.

Comment: Good idea. Yeah I was able to get it to work. I found out about the spacers later on. That was the missing link.